# Uncertainty derived from assumptions

Tags: experimental-physics, error-analysis

When determining certain quantities experimentally, we sometimes make theoretical assumptions. For example, we might assume some variable remains constant during the measuring process (when in fact they vary slightly) or we might assume ideal behavior of a gas in order to determine experimentally some important value we want to know.

My problem is that I don’t know how to study these types of theoretical assumptions from the point of view of error analysis. Those assumptions definitely cause uncertainties to be greater, but I don’t know if I’m supposed to quantify them and include them in my error analysis or not, and, if so, how could I do such a thing?

One can easily quantify certain uncertainties, but how could someone possibly quantify such thing as ‘the error caused by assuming ideal behavior in a real gas’ (that’s just an example, I’m not concerned with any particular case).

Comment: Monte Carlo programs designed for the specific experiment can do that.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method#Physical_sciences

Answer (score 2):

There are two limiting cases for the kind of scenario you are describing, where you use a model $M$ that does not perfectly match physical reality.

- If the error you make by using $M$ is much smaller than other sources of uncertainty in your experiment (for example, statistical uncertainty), then this is a mild error you can "sweep under the rug." You can consider $M$ to be a good enough *approximation* to the actual physical system. This is nothing to be ashamed of; any experimental analysis will involve making approximations.
- If the error you make by using $M$ is the largest source of uncertainty in your experiment, then you are dominated by **systematic uncertainty**. This is uncertainty that does not decrease as you collect more data. There are different strategies you can take. First, since errors due to using $M$ are so important in this case, you should try to improve $M$ to have it match physical reality as closely as possible. Assuming you have already done this, you want to try to understand the difference between your model and reality. If your model has some parameters that are unknown, you can see what range of predictions your model makes as you vary these parameters over reasonable ranges. You can try using different models making different approximations and see what *those* predict, and get a range of predictions. You could try to compare the predictions of $M$ to measurements, and apply some empirical correction to $M$ to make its predictions closer to observations. There is no "one-size-fits-all" solution to systematic uncertainties; you need to use whatever makes the most sense for your problem.
- In between these cases, you need to decide the relative importance the error you are making using $M$, and other sources of uncertainty, and decide where to spend effort to reduce or quantify the uncertainty.

Answer (score 1):

Using the probability measure of uncertainty, such assumptions are typically considered as boundary conditions. For example, in estimating the confidence interval for the probability of failure based on a sample, the assumption that the binomial probability distribution is appropriate is a boundary condition.

The assumption is treated as a boundary condition, because for many situations, you have insufficient state of knowledge to assign a probability distribution over the set of possible outcomes for the assumption; for example, all the possible probability distributions possible for a describing the probability of a failure (binomial, hypergeometric, etc).  The rest of this discussion assumes this is the case.

Probability deals with aleatory (random) uncertainty but does not address epistemic (state of knowledge) uncertainty very well. The uncertainty associated with the assumptions is epistemic uncertainty.  The theory of evidence (due to Dempster and Shafer) is one way to quantify epistemic uncertainty. In application, evidence is assigned and based on the evidence, lower and upper bounds on a probability, called belief and plausibility, can be estimated.  The probability is somewhere within the belief to plausibility interval.  Any valid probability distribution (normal, lognormal, etc. for a continuous random variable) whose outcomes are assigned probability consistent with the evidence will give a probability somewhere with the belief to plausibility interval; so, the issue of epistemic uncertainty as to the appropriate probability distribution to use is addressed.

A simple example using belief/plausibility is total ignorance for a variable, such as the probability of heads for a coin you cannot examine.  The coin could be two headed, biased tails, etc.  For this case you assign evidence of 1.0 to the set {Heads, Tails} resulting in a belief to plausibility interval of [0, 1] for both the probability of Heads and for the probability of Tails, a true reflection that any probability of Heads or Tails can occur.  With improved state of knowledge, the epistemic uncertainty is reduced, reflected as a decrease in the belief to plausibility interval; for example, as you toss the coin you assign finer degrees of evidence. With no epistemic uncertainty both belief and plausibility are the same value, the probability.  There is a technique to combine, "convolve", the uncertainty from a combination of random variables to generate the uncertainty for the combined variables (a random vector) as a belief to plausibility distribution.

As a real-world example, in the past I evaluated the Risk of a large set of terrorist acts (IEDs, bio attacks, cyber attacks, etc. against a set of targets) as a combination of three random variables: Threat, Vulnerability, and Consequence. Initially, Threat was treated as boundary condition because of insufficient state of knowledge to assign a probability distribution to Threat. The Risk was evaluated conditional on the Threat; that is, both Vulnerability and Consequence were assigned probability distributions conditional on the Threat, Vulnerability depended on the Threat resources and Consequence depended on the Threat technical expertise.  Later, to address the uncertainty in Threat, the theory of evidence was used and evidence was assigned to Threat; ultimately, evidence was also assigned to Vulnerability and Consequence.  The uncertainty in Risk for each terrorist act was generated as a belief/plausibility distribution formed by "convolving" the evidence for Threat, Vulnerability, and Consequence using the mathematics of the theory of evidence. (Actually, Threat, Vulnerability, and Consequence each were formed from numerous constituent random variables; for example, Threat depended on Adversary Resources (vehicles, weapons, numbers, etc.) and Adversary Technical Expertise.)  The evaluation was performed with a computer code.

Also, many years ago I was involved in evaluating how uncertainty was considered in disease propagation models.  At that time, the models I evaluated addressed aleatory uncertainty, but did not epistemic uncertainty very well.  As a simplified example, a model assumed a probability of contagion and modeled the uncertainty in that probability using a Bayesian approach.  For a new disease the uncertainty in the probability of contagion with the Bayesian approach can be way off if the assumed prior is inaccurate and there is little information available to update the prior to the posterior. Over time with sufficient information a poor prior can be updated to a better posterior, but for the early stages of a new disease the model can be highly inaccurate.  A better approach is to model the uncertainty in the probability of contagion as belief/plausibility interval based on assigning evidence.  With this approach, instead of generating one curve for the probability of exceedance over the range of casualties, you generate two curves for exceedance of casualties, the belief for exceedance and the plausibility for exceedance, with the imprecisely known probability of exceedance curve somewhere in between these two curves. This approach better reflects the uncertainty in causalities early in the disease, by more accurately considering the significant epistemic uncertainty in the probability of contagion.  I am not familiar with the state-of-the-art disease progression models, but I suspect they may suffer from a similar deficiency, based on the inaccurate results they predicted in the early stages of the COVID pandemic.

Related to your example of a gas with uncertainty as to the model that best describes the behavior of the gas, here is one approach. You can treat the model for the gas as a random variable whose outcome is described with a set of different models (the universe of discourse for gas models).  With insufficient state of knowledge to assign a probability distribution over the model outcomes, you can assign evidence over the set of models.  Then, you can propagate the uncertainty for the gas model with the uncertainties in other variables in your evaluation, and end up with a belief to plausibility distribution for your results.  To be more specific, suppose you wish to predict the work done by the gas $W$ with changes in pressure $P$ and volume $V$ using a polytropic relationship $PV^n= constant$. $W = \int_{V_{initial}}^{V_{final}} P(V)dV = {(P_{final}V_{final} - P_{initial}V_{initial)} \over {1 - n}}$ assuming $n \ne 1$. But, $n$ depends on your gas model.  You perform a series of measurements for $P$ and $V$ that have sufficient information to generate probability distributions for these variables.  Conditional on the gas model (given a model) you estimate the uncertainty in $W_{conditional on the model}$ (a probability distribution) by "convolving" (perhaps numerically with sampling) the probability distributions for $P$ and $V$ using the relationship $W_{conditional on the model} = {(P_{final}V_{final} - P_{initial}V_{initial)} \over {1 - n_{model}}}$; then combine these probability distributions with the uncertainty in the gas model (belief/plausibility interval) to generate a belief/plausibility uncertainty for the value of $W$.  This is not a simple process.

The textbook, A Mathematical Theory of Evidence, by Glen Shafer provides the mathematical details.

Hope this helps.